# Search in custom component

Tags: joomla-2.5, php, custom-component, search

How can I improve the Search component in joomla 2.5 to set search by my custom component?
Can't find, where I can modify the search request to database.

UPDATE:

With help of [Rene Korss](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/3944/rene-korss) I solve the problem.

1. Made a custom search plugin with files:

   - customsearch.php

```
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
require_once JPATH_SITE .  '/components/com_nhotel/helpers/route.php';

class plgSearchCustomsearch extends JPlugin {

    function __construct(& $subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
        $this->loadLanguage();
    }


    function onContentSearchAreas() {
        static $areas = array(
            'customsearch' => 'Customsearch'
        );
        return $areas;
    }

     function onContentSearch( $text, $phrase='', $ordering='', $areas=null ) {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $user   = JFactory::getUser();
        $groups = implode(',', $user->getAuthorisedViewLevels());

        // If the array is not correct, return it:
        if (is_array( $areas )) {
            if (!array_intersect( $areas, array_keys( $this->onContentSearchAreas() ) )) {
                return array();
            }
        }

        $text = trim( $text );

        // Return Array when nothing was filled in.
        if ($text == '') {
            return array();
        }

        $wheres = array();

        switch ($phrase) {

            // Search exact
            case 'exact':
                $text       = $db->Quote( '%'.$db->escape( $text, true ).'%', false );
                $wheres2    = array();
                $wheres2[]  = 'LOWER(a.greeting) LIKE '.$text;
                $where      = '(' . implode( ') OR (', $wheres2 ) . ')';
                break;

            // Search all or any
            case 'all':
            case 'any':

                // Set default
            default:
                $words  = explode( ' ', $text );
                $wheres = array();
                foreach ($words as $word)
                {
                    $word       = $db->Quote( '%'.$db->escape( $word, true ).'%', false );
                    $wheres2    = array();
                    $wheres2[]  = 'LOWER(a.greeting) LIKE '.$word;
                    $wheres[]   = implode( ' OR ', $wheres2 );
                }
                $where = '(' . implode( ($phrase == 'all' ? ') AND (' : ') OR ('), $wheres ) . ')';
                break;
        }

        // Ordering of the results
        switch ( $ordering ) {

            //Alphabetic, ascending
            case 'alpha':
                $order = 'a.greeting ASC';
                break;

            // Oldest first
            case 'oldest':

                // Popular first
            case 'popular':

                // Newest first
            case 'newest':

                // Default setting: alphabetic, ascending
            default:
                $order = 'a.greeting ASC';
        }

        $section = JText::_( 'Customsearch' );

        $query  = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('a.greeting AS title, a.description AS text');
        $query->select('"1" AS browsernav');
        $query->from('#__customtable AS a');
        $query->order($order);
        $query->where($where);
        $db->setQuery( $query, 0, $limit );
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

        foreach($rows as $key => $row) {
            // This link I will correct later to my link structure
            $rows[$key]->href = 'custom_link_to_result_article';
        }

        //Return the search results in an array
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

- [customsearch.xml](https://docs.joomla.org/index.php?title=J2.5:Creating_a_search_plugin)

next, I install the plugin and switch it on. Ready to use!

Comment: Joomla! 2.5´s how to create search plugin docs is [here](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_search_plugin). You said that 3.x one was understandable, what exactly was understandable?

Comment: I tried to make a search plugin by manual. But there is no result. I think the problem in SQL query and i don't understand how the switch "exact-all-any" working. The plugin pack is here - [link](http://aquarida-tour.kz/docs/hotelsearch_plugin.zip)

Comment: In plugin I tried to search rsults from DB table - #__nhotel. Searching by greeting and description, where state = 1.

Comment: I looked at your plugin. Your query is definately incorrect. Use `print_r($db->getQuery());` to print out resulting SQL query and fix it. For starters `c.state=1` in `WHERE` is not needed, since you don't join categories in. And `$case_when` and `$case_when1` is not needed etc. Just go step by step. Also, you are searching by `a.name`, it seems your table dosen't have such column. Try searching by `title` (`a.greeting`) to get going.

Comment: Made a corrects, but there is already no results. And what about output, should I do corrects of components/com_search/views/search/tmpl/default_results.php?

Comment: No. You don't need to edit any core files. Tha'ts what plugins are for - to avoid this. Maybe you could somehow show me your DB table dump and your current code? You just have to get query right.

Comment: Yes, I can. This is my plugin and table dump please - [link](http://www.aquarida-tour.kz/docs/hotelsearch.zip)

Comment: Ok. Got it to work. You have to have `class plgSearchHotelsearch extends JPlugin{` around yout functions. After this it immediately started to work (although showing all results). And finaly add `$query->where($where);` if `$where` has some value. Should be ok to go.

Comment: Yohoo! It's working! Thank you very much. Where can I vote for this answer?

Comment: Please edit your question - add your initial code to it and tell the exact issue. Then we can vote to reopen this and I can answer it with already existing solution.

Comment: @user3774771 Can you confirm that the code posted above is the broken code? It isn't clear from your edit.

Comment: If your UPDATE is "ready to use", you should remove that section from you question, post it as sn answer, and mark your answer with the green tick.  @user3774771

Answer (score -2):

You can't use joomla search engine for custom component.

The only thing if component doesn't have it's own search engine, write a new component which will look in a specific place of Your data base.

Comment: And what about search plugin for custom component? I found the manual to make this plugin [link](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_search_plugin), but it is for joomla 3.0 and not really understandable -(

Comment: Try something like [Joomla extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/search-a-indexing/site-search/universal-ajax-live-search) it has some of the extensions included maybe it will have yours.

Comment: And by the way never try it but i looks kinda cool [component-creator](https://www.component-creator.com/en/) maybe it will give some ideas for You:)

Comment: This component "Universal Ajax Search" will search only by articles and/or vm products. My component have it own DB table and won't be included in search results i think.

Comment: Actually you can use search engine on your custom components, you just need to develop the [plugins to index your contents](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Smart_Search_plug-in).